# UTC and local time issue

Tags: timezone

I've a laptop which dual boots Windows 10 and Ubuntu (16.10).
I'm based in India and the time that I see is 5.30 hours ahead. i.e. 5.30PM when the local time is 12.00PM
I've tried to set the Hw clock with

```
sudo hwclock --localtime
```

This is what I see

```
sudo hwclock -r
2017-03-04 17:30:43.420286+5:30
```

Timezone
    cat /etc/timezone
    Asia/Kolkata

Raw output

```
sudo hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.28.2
Using the /dev interface to the clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2017/03/04 12:44:07
Hw clock time : 2017/03/04 12:44:07 = 1488631447 seconds since 1969
Time since last adjustment is 1488631447 seconds
Calculated Hardware Clock drift is 0.000000 seconds
2017-03-04 18:14:06.075863+5:30
```

In the Time Applet I've set it to get time automatically and that still reutrns this time.

Any help is much appreciated

EDIT: This is the solution

In terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/rcS
```

You may need to install gksu. In which case:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

else ensure the file says:

```
UTC=no
```

Save and exit

Boot to Windows.
Set correct time with the time applet.
Boot to Ubuntu.

The correct time should be up